# Decorate dates on DatePicker in JetpackCompose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-datepicker

I am looking for a way to decorate dates in DatePicker in jetpack compose.
So far I was using [prolificinteractive material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) but I am trying to use as much compose stuff as possible. With prolificinteractive material-calendarview I was able to draw dots underneath the dates which pass a certain condition.

I could not figure out a way to decorate the dates using compose DatePicker.

Comment: Can you post an example or a screen?